# "Centralized Relational Databases" vs. "Decentralized Blockchain " : Which one is really more scalable?

Tags: blockchain, scalability, database, decentralization

There are many research papers on **problem of scalability of blockchains**:

Just as an example : [An Overview of Blockchain Technology: Architecture, Consensus, and Future Trends](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Hong-Ning_Dai/publication/318131748_An_Overview_of_Blockchain_Technology_Architecture_Consensus_and_Future_Trends/links/59d71faa458515db19c915a1/An-Overview-of-Blockchain-Technology-Architecture-Consensus-and-Future-Trends.pdf)

However, (usually by some companies which uses `blockchain` technology), it's mentioned that one of the **advantages** of `blockchain` against centralized `relational databases`, is **scalability**.

Just as an example : [WePower White Paper](https://icorating.com/upload/whitepaper/CDt62AS6IjlVUY8CNdHk0aYJycsT7ez8Yp5HgKod.pdf).

> **Quote from this white paper:**
>
> *Relational databases are adequate in many applications and situations.
>   However, sustainability and scalability are limited with these
>   databases. From the perspective of sector transformation in trading
>   and digital infrastructure creation, transforming energy production to
>   100% renewable, the answer was to utilize a public blockchain.*

**Is it a correct proposition?**

Comment: blockchain algorithm can't be scaled because it was designed to be serial at core. poor are the people who are still looking for ways to scale, it is an impossible thing to do.

Comment: @Nulik Thank you, what do you mean by `to be serial at core` ? Thanks

Comment: I mean it is not parallel. Just like a processor in Von Neumann architecture. If you noted last decade the speed of the microprocessors decreased due to the speed of light limit. Now the only way to scale is to rewrite the software for parallel architecture. Same thing with the blockchain. You must parallelize tasks, but with the blockchain, the serialness of the processes is the main feature. It is because of this serial property that the blockhain technology has become so reliable. A hash of a hash of a hash of a hash .... you can't parallelize this.

Comment: @Nulik blockchains are absolutely parallelizable, that's mainly what sharding is doing. On top of that, parallel processing of transactions is easily possible within blocks if transactions were required to name a list of accounts they touched. If the list of touched accounts don't overlap for two transactions, then the two transactions can be processed in parallel.

Comment: @flygoing I would be very careful with the `absolutely` word , in your place. Transactions already say the accounts they are touching, it is the `From` and `To` field of the TX. Then, how do you derive the list of parallel transactions? By a `SERIAL` process. See it? You can't escape serialness. After you process the transactions, you will have to tie up the work that has done by creating a hash on all touched accounts, thats another `SERIAL` process. If you have network latency, your serial algorithm is going to be dead slow. That's what I am talking about

Comment: @Nulik `to` and `from` aren't the only accounts a transaction touches. If `to` is a contract, then the contract can touch any number of accounts. The transaction would have to list *all* the touched accounts, not just the account it's sending directly to. If `to` and `from` were the only touched accounts, then parallelization would be very easy. Of course there's a point where serial work has to be done, but that's less than 5% of the work. Parallelizing the 95% of the work into, say, 8 threads is still a ~75% improvement in efficiency. Sharding should be able to do even more than that though.

Comment: @flygoing ohh, but I forgot one thing: don't ever try to parallelize Ethereum because it may result in brain damage. In Ethereum there is one thing called State Trie, it is a tree of all modifications to account balances. This process is holding a big lock on every attempt to make Ethereum scalable. You won't be able to parallelize it ever.

Comment: @flygoing, I know that a contract can send money to many accounts, I was just simplifying.

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://medium.com/@bitrewards/blockchain-scalability-the-issues-and-proposed-solutions-2ec2c7ac98f0) article addresses current scalability issues of the blockchain and potential solutions for those issues.

Comment: Thank you, but my question is which one are really more scalable ? Thanks

Comment: RDBMS is more scalable than blockchain. The blockchain is definitely having storage and processing limitations.

Comment: So you are not agreed with the **quote** from that white paper in my question? Thanks

Comment: Yes, I do not agree with the quote from that white paper.